# How to recognize that short code blocks can be refactored into something cleaner?

Tags: language-agnostic, refactoring, code-cleanup

i have a bit of code that i wrote a few weeks ago (the code's purpose isn't so much important as its structure):

```
if (_image.Empty)
{
   //Use the true image size if they haven't specified a custom size
   if (_glyphSize.Width > 0)
      imageSize.Width = _glyphSize.Width //override
   else
      imageSize.Width = _image.GetWidth;

   if (_glyphSize.Height > 0) then
      imageSize.Height = _glyphSize.Height
   else
      imageSize.Height = _image.GetHeight
}
else
{
   //No image, but they can still override it with a custom size
   if (_glyphSize.Width > 0) then
      imageSize.Width = _glyphSize.Width
   else
      imageSize.Width = 0;

   if (_glyphSize.Height > 0)
      imageSize.Height = _glyphSize.Height
   else
      imageSize.Height := 0;
}
```

i was going over it tonight, and as i was cleaning it up, i realized that the cleaned version is must more concise:

```
//Figure out the final image width
if (_glyphSize.Width > 0)
   imageSize.Width = _glyphSize.Width
else if (not _glyph.Empty)
   imageSize.Width = _glyph.GetWidth
else
   imageSize.Width = 0;

//Figure out the final image height
if (_glyphSize.Height > 0)
   imageSize.Height = _glyphSize.Height
else if (not _glyph.Empty)
   imageSize.Height = _glyph.GetHeight
else
   imageSize.Height = 0;
```

**Note:** i've trimmed down the code to bare logical flow, and obfsucated the source language.

In the end i took the nested `if`'s, and inverted them. Doing that allowed this shortening. My question is: how can i recognize this in the future?

What are the tell-tale signs that i've just written some code that can be refactored into something shorter?

---

Another example i had from a few weeks ago was something akin to a permission check: the user can perform an action:

- if they have the permission they can do it
- if they don't have the permission, but the override is in effect

Which i initially coded as:

```
if ((HasPermission || (!HasPermission and OverrideEnabled))
{
   ...do stuff
}
```

The logical conditions on that `if` clause seemed kind of wordy. i tried to reach back to my boolean algebra course to figure out how to simplify it. In the end i could do it, so i ended up drawing a truth table:

```
Permission  Override   Result
    0           0        0
    0           1        1
    1           0        1
    1           1        1
```

Which when i look at it is an **OR** operation. So my `if` statement became:

```
if (HasPermission  or OverrideEnabled)
{
   ...
}
```

Which is obvious and simple. And so now i'm wondering how i couldn't see that to begin with.

---

Which brings me back to my SO question: What tell-tale signs could/should i be looking for in order to recognize that some block of code needs some TLC?

Comment: shorter doesn't not always mean easier to maintain most of the time it means the opposite, maintainable should be the first goal after get it working.

Comment: @fuzzy: exactly why i was after shorter. The initial longer version seemed too complicated. So in this case shorter is better. But if i had tried to make it even shorter with a trinary operator, then you have permission to shoot me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some guidelines from Code Complete, off the top of my head. That is a good book to get for this sort of thing.

1. Nested if-else and repeated statements in blocks
2. Long for-loops
3. Repeated lines/statements or frequently used operations can be placed in a function
4. If for some reasons you are copying and pasting a line of code over and over again

I found discrete maths to have an influence in how I wrote if statements now. Usually, I see I am writing two same IF statements in 2 blocks, then I would do some mental 'factoring'.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically related to boolean evaluation, it's worth noting that most(?) modern languages implement lazy evaluation.

That is, if "a" is true, then `if(a)` and `if(a or b)` are logically and functionally equivelant; the interpreter stops evaluating when it sees `or` after a true variable. This isn't very important when `a` and `b` are variables, but if they're callables [e.g. `if(a() or b())`], `b()` will not get evaluated when `a` is true.

You can save a lot of keystrokes (and processor time) by learning this well:

```
if(!userExists()):
    if(!createUser()):
        errorHandling()
    else:
        doStuff()
else: doStuff()
```

becomes

```
if(userExists() or createUser()): doStuff()
else: errorHandling()
```

Comment: i'm not keen on `if` logical clauses that change the state of the system. And besides, some compilers have the option of turning that feature off, in which case your code can subtly introduce errors.

Answer (score 1):

Well done.  Now, when I see this:

```
//Figure out the final image width
if (_glyphSize.Width > 0)
...

//Figure out the final image height
if (_glyphSize.Height > 0)
...
```

I think there is still more refactoring to do.  Extracting code into methods isn't just a great way to eliminate redundant code.  It's also a great way to make the code self documenting:

I'd be inclined to reduce the code to:

```
set_final_image_size
```

With set_final_image_size and its minions defined like so:

```
def set_final_image_size:
  imageSize.Width = final_image_width;
  imageSize.Height = final_image_height;

def final_image_width:
  if (_glyphSize.Width > 0)
     return _glyphSize.Width;
  else if (not _glyph.Empty)
     return _glyph.GetWidth;
  else
     return 0;

def final_image_height:
  if (_glyphSize.Height > 0)
     return _glyphSize.Height;
  else if (not _glyph.Empty)
     return _glyph.GetHeight;
  else
     return 0;
```

Comment: Not sure i like the idea of forcing a stack push and subroutine call for something that easily doesn't need to be.

Comment: We live in an age of plenty, where the traditional constraints--stack, CPU, disk--no long exist for most applications.  Why optimize for the machine when you could be making things better for the human?

Comment: Also, a good compiler will inline that if there is a gain by doing so. That probably won't happen in an interpreted language, but then again, performance probably isn't at the top of the priority list then.

Comment: i also don't like the idea of introducing a method that contains 3 lines. Cause now what was three statements has become four, and in order to understand what's going on you have to follow a jump. i can agree refactoring out duplicated, or lengthy, code segments to their own method. But replacing a code block who's job is to calculate the final size by splitting it up into 2 more functions? You're not helping readability, or maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've separated the width and height logic, and noticed that it's identical - what if you were to add, say, `getDimension(Direction direction)` and `setDimension(Direction direction, int length)` to your classes?  Now you've got

```
if (_glyphSize.getDimension(direction) > 0)
   imageSize.setDimension(direction, _glyphSize.getDimension(direction))
else if (not _glyph.Empty)
   imageSize.setDimension(direction, _glyph.getDimension(direction))
else
   imageSize.setDimension(direction, 0);
```

Extracting the local brings us:

```
length = _glyphSize.getDimension(direction);
if (length > 0)
   imageSize.setDimension(direction, length)
else if (not _glyph.Empty)
   imageSize.setDimension(direction, _glyph.getDimension(direction))
else
   imageSize.setDimension(direction, 0);
```

taking it a little further:

```
length = _glyphSize.getDimension(direction);
if (length == 0 && !_glyph.Empty)
    length = _glyph.getDimension(direction);
imageSize.setDimension(direction, length);
```

Which, to my eyes at least, is starting to look pretty nice.

Comment: i think this is overboard.  imageSize is a structure, with two members: Width and Height. You're replacing size.Width = value with size.SetDimenion(directionWidth, value);  If anything was less readable it's that.

Comment: @Ian You're of course entitled to your opinion, but I have found that our treatment of X & Y typically creates a lot of duplicate code, and that eliminating that duplication makes the code easier to understand and reduces errors.